# XMLScriptBuilder can use the intern method to reduce heap memory?

Tags: mybatis

**your text**
There are many repeated IfSqlNode in the project, resulting in too much memory in the project.

When I tried to read the TEXT_NODE in the parseDynamicTags method and read the use of intern() in the test attributes in ifhandler, it can reduce the heap memory occupation, but this is not a good solution.

Is there any good processing method to reduce MyBatis to reduce the stack memory occupation?

```
 String data = child.getStringBody("").intern();
 String test = nodeToHandle.getStringAttribute("test").intern();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pwkF.png)